# how to show these problem of integration $\alpha 1_E \leq g$ could become $\alpha \mu(E) \leq \int_E g d\mu$

Tags: integration

how to show these by using monotonic and linearity that $\alpha 1_E \leq g$  could become $\alpha \mu(E) \leq \int_E g d\mu$, please give a HINT for me..thanks

Comment: Is $g$ a simple function... how did you define integral of simple functions??

Comment: yes $g$ is simple function

Comment: So, $g= \sum _{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i$ where $f_i$ is charactersitic function... Do you know how to define integral of $g$ in this case??

Comment: no i can'nt can you show me?

Comment: No, No, what do you mean when you say $\int_E g d\mu$??

Comment: how to relate it into the definition in my question..?

Comment: as $g= \sum _{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i$, we have  $\int_E g d\mu= \sum _{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mu(E_i)$... do you see the result now?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik yes, but how about the sigma? how to applied the monotonic and linear in here?

Comment: even before that, let $f,g$ be two simple functions such that $f\leq g$ i mean, $f$ has less number of characteristic functions than that of $g$.. This should imply atleast intutively $\int_E f d\mu \leq \int_E g d\mu$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your idea is to prove $f\leq g$ implies $\int_{E} f \leq \int _E g$

I would suggest you to just see for characteristic functions...

i.e., let $f\leq g$ and $f,g$ be two characteristic functions on $E$ (please see this $E$ is same for both $f,g$)

by $f\leq g$ , we mean $\alpha_i\leq \alpha_j$ where $f=\alpha_i \chi(E)$ and $g=\alpha_j \chi(E)$

Now, do you see what is $\int_{E} f$,$\int _E g$???

$\int_{E} f := \alpha_i \mu(E)$ and $\int_{E} g := \alpha_j \mu(E)$

You have $\alpha_i\leq \alpha_j$ and $\mu(E)>0$.

So, $\alpha_i\mu(E)\leq \alpha_j\mu(E)$ i.e., $\int_{E} f\leq \int _E g$

Now, I guess This would suggest you to see for simple functions....

Comment: yes i got it, thanks @praphulla

Comment: It would be nice if you can do this for simple functions and write that down i this.. That might be helpful for others...

Comment: I will try my best to make you to do it by yourself... please go ahead...

Comment: Ok. YOu know how does $f\leq g$ implies $\int_E f \leq \int _E g$ for characteristic functions $f,g$... How do you think simple functions look like??? what does it mean when you say $f\leq g$ for simple functions????